# No Dropbox app on Ubuntu BQ mobile

Tags: dropbox

I use my mobile phone, mainly, for work purposes. At work we use dropbox as a shared drive for documents.

Unfortunately there's no dropbox app yet for Ubuntu phone. Do you know if someone's working on  the development of a dropbox app? This is a very urgent matter for me, and dropbox is widely used by a huge number of people.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried uDropCabin in the Ubuntu App store?

You can get it [here](https://appstore.bhdouglass.com/app/com.ubuntu.developer.bobo1993324.udropcabin)

Comment: I second this, uDropCabin doesn't to automatic syncing, but you can upload and download files on demand with it.